# AngularJS Multiple View

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

Default View

```html
<html>
  <head>
    //angular source
  </head>
  <body ng-app="angular">
    //header
    // login and register button 
    <div ng-view></div>
    // footer
  </body>
</html>
```

Profile View

```html
<html>
  <head>
    //angular source
   </head>
   <body ng-app="angular">
     //header and menu
     <div ng-view></div>
     // footer
    </body>
</html>
```

When i try to log in, i am in Default View. After successfully logged in, i want to move a new view (Profile View). Is it possible in angularJS ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the difference is in the header and menu? Why not just use something like `ng-show` to conditionally check which view you're in (using `$location`) and update like that.

Or if you *really* want to keep those pages separate, you could create new static content that loads a different angular app that's 'logged in'. But I don't think this is good design.

Comment: I don't want to show visitors `using Firebug or etc` what `menu or something` they are getting after login. That's why i don't want to use `ng-show`. As you say, it is not possible to move one view to another. Is it ??

Comment: Oh, well you can use [ng-if] (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) (and I think `ng-switch`), which won't render the menu at all if the condition is false (rather than merely hide it, like `ng-show` would):
"If the expression is falsy then the element is removed from the DOM tree"

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do make user of AngularJS Routes

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/routes.html

just go through with this tutorial you will get some hint